# Query AWS Timestream with Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, amazon-timestream

I'm using Spring Boot as backend framework and I would like to store and query some time series data into the AWS Timestream DB service.

I see that AWS suggests to use the AWS Java SDK, but is there a way to use Spring Data JPA, which I tipically use to manage relational data in a Spring Boot application, to easily perform CRUD operations on a Timestream DB?